# Indent to next indentation level with >>

Tags: indentation

From time to time I have to work with code that isn't indented to the level of indentation I have Vim set up to (4 spaces per level), usually after copy/pasting something in the file. I usually make do with `<<` and `>>`. The problem is they don't jump to the next indentation level, they just add or subtract 4 spaces.

If I have code like this

```
if condition:
    do this
   do that
```

doing `>>` on `do that` will result in

```
if condition:
    do this
       do that
```

I want it to go to this

```
if condition:
    do this
    do that
```

Beside easily  matching the indentation of the line above, I want it to jump to the next level of indentation, not add 4 spaces.

This is what I have in my .vimrc regarding indentation

```
:set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
```

Comment: If you also have `filetype plugin indent on` in your `.vimrc`, filetype (and plugin) indentation-related rules will apply. I.e. check what your `tabstop` value *actually* is (`set tabstop?` will do; same for the other settings), when editing, and change those values by adding your line to an 'after' file, something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/159066/5000478

Comment: `>>` and `<<` respectively add and remove indent which is not what you want. What you want is "formatting", which is done with `==`.

Comment: could also map `:nnoremap >> ^i<tab><esc>` if you really want tab behaviour on `>>`

Comment: @romainl `==` will jump to the level of the line above. While a good thing to know, it would not work in all cases I'm interested in. As an addition to the question, what I want is for `>>` and `<<` to indent/dedent up to the next multiple of shiftwidth from the border in that direction.

Comment: No, `==` uses either `equalexpr` or `equalprg` to reformat the given lines.

Comment: @Dumitru I'm not sure, but maybe you could try enabling the `'shiftround'` option in your vimrc: `set shiftround`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use one of the commands `{count}>>`, `{count}<<`, `>{motion}` or `<{motion}`, on some lines which have already been indented, and you want their new indentation level to be a multiple of your `'shiftwidth'` option value, you can enable the `'shiftround'` option, and add this line in your `vimrc`:

```
set shiftround
```

Answer (score 2):

If you always want `>>` to indent to the next tabstop and `<<` to delete to the last tabstop, you can rebind them like so:

```
:nnoremap << ^i<BS><esc>
:nnoremap >> ^i<tab><esc>
```

This will move the cursor, but you could probably do some mark trickery to move it back. `^` doesn't leave a `m'` mark, but you can leave one manually inside the binding.